# Need Help To Get XML Values In Array Using POWERSHELL

Tags: arrays, xml, powershell, xml-parsing

I have an XML Output from a FIRMWARE CHECK Script on a HPE Server.
I want to create an array to define `FIRMWARE_NAME VALUE` = `FIRMWARE_VERSION VALUE` for each index.

As you can see that Path is not consistent and there can be more or less index from server to server, hence creating a loop fails, probably because I am not good with PowerShell too and hence seeking some help.

A demo script is below:

```
$xml = [xml]@"
<HEAD>
<RIBCL VERSION="2.23">
<RESPONSE
    STATUS="0x0000"
    MESSAGE='No error'
     />
<GET_EMBEDDED_HEALTH_DATA>
     <FIRMWARE_INFORMATION>
          <INDEX_1>
               <FIRMWARE_NAME VALUE = "iLO"/>
               <FIRMWARE_VERSION VALUE = "2.40 Dec 02 2015"/>
          </INDEX_1>
          <INDEX_2>
               <FIRMWARE_NAME VALUE = "System ROM"/>
               <FIRMWARE_VERSION VALUE = "I31 06/01/2015"/>
          </INDEX_2>
          <INDEX_3>
               <FIRMWARE_NAME VALUE = "Redundant System ROM"/>
               <FIRMWARE_VERSION VALUE = "I31 04/01/2015"/>
          </INDEX_3>
          <INDEX_4>
               <FIRMWARE_NAME VALUE = "Intelligent Provisioning"/>
               <FIRMWARE_VERSION VALUE = "1.62.31"/>
          </INDEX_4>
          <INDEX_5>
               <FIRMWARE_NAME VALUE = "Intelligent Platform Abstraction Data"/>
               <FIRMWARE_VERSION VALUE = "1.55"/>
          </INDEX_5>
          <INDEX_6>
               <FIRMWARE_NAME VALUE = "System ROM Bootblock"/>
               <FIRMWARE_VERSION VALUE = "03/05/2013"/>
          </INDEX_6>
          <INDEX_7>
               <FIRMWARE_NAME VALUE = "Power Management Controller Firmware"/>
               <FIRMWARE_VERSION VALUE = "3.3"/>
               <FIRMWARE_FAMILY VALUE = "0Ch"/>
          </INDEX_7>
          <INDEX_8>
               <FIRMWARE_NAME VALUE = "Power Management Controller Firmware Bootloader"/>
               <FIRMWARE_VERSION VALUE = "2.7"/>
          </INDEX_8>
          <INDEX_9>
               <FIRMWARE_NAME VALUE = "System Programmable Logic Device"/>
               <FIRMWARE_VERSION VALUE = "Version 0x13"/>
          </INDEX_9>
          <INDEX_10>
               <FIRMWARE_NAME VALUE = "Server Platform Services (SPS) Firmware"/>
               <FIRMWARE_VERSION VALUE = "2.1.7.E7.4"/>
          </INDEX_10>
          <INDEX_11>
               <FIRMWARE_NAME VALUE = "Smart Array P220i Controller"/>
               <FIRMWARE_VERSION VALUE = "6.68"/>
          </INDEX_11>
          <INDEX_12>
               <FIRMWARE_NAME VALUE = "HP FlexFabric 10Gb 2-port 554FLB Adapter"/>
               <FIRMWARE_VERSION VALUE = "10.5.155.0"/>
          </INDEX_12>
     </FIRMWARE_INFORMATION>
</GET_EMBEDDED_HEALTH_DATA>
</RIBCL>
</HEAD>
"@
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT: in the array

> iLO= 2.40 Dec 02 2015
>
> System ROM= I31 06/01/2015
>
> Redundant System ROM= I31 04/01/2015
>
> Intelligent Provisioning= 1.62.31
>
> Intelligent Platform Abstraction Data= 1.55
>
> System ROM Bootblock= 41338
>
> Power Management Controller Firmware= 3.3
>
> Power Management Controller Firmware Bootloader= 2.7
>
> System Programmable Logic Device= Version 0x13
>
> Server Platform Services (SPS) Firmware= 2.1.7.E7.4
>
> Smart Array P220i Controller= 6.68
>
> HP FlexFabric 10Gb 2-port 554FLB Adapter= 10.5.155.0

Comment: Question is answered, I am not sure how to close the thread, can Admin Help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to just add this as a comment to Martin Brandl's answer but I couldn't get the formatting of the code to look right.

To expand on Martin Brandl's answer, if you wanted the results in object form, you could do something like this:

```
$FirmwareVersions = $xml.DocumentElement.RIBCL.GET_EMBEDDED_HEALTH_DATA.FIRMWARE_INFORMATION.ChildNodes | ForEach-Object {
    [pscustomobject]@{
        Name = $_.FIRMWARE_NAME.Value;
        Version = $_.FIRMWARE_VERSION.Value
    }
}
```

**Based on your comments**:

If you want one object with the property names to be the different devices and the value to be the firmware levels (and then exported to CSV), here is how I would do that:

```
$FirmwareVersions = New-Object -TypeName PSObject
$xml.DocumentElement.RIBCL.GET_EMBEDDED_HEALTH_DATA.FIRMWARE_INFORMATION.ChildNodes | ForEach-Object {
    $FirmwareVersions | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $_.FIRMWARE_NAME.Value -Value $_.FIRMWARE_VERSION.Value
}
$FirmwareVersions | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path .\FirmwareVersions.csv
```

There may be a shorter syntax for doing that, but this was the way that came most natural to me. The code creates a new custom object and then cycles through the child nodes of the XML to add a new property to the custom object with the firmware name and the firmware value.

Comment: Yes, thats what I meant. You can also just assign `$FirmwareVersions` to `$xml...`. No need to declare it and += add the objects ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the help, I am trying various combinations provided by both of you, thanks for the quick reply.

Comment: I tried your solution, and its almost what I need.
I am trying to export this output in a CSV File, where Column Headings will be the Firmware Name and Version will be in Subsequent Rows, When I use your method I am getting the Name / Version in Column Headers and Firmware Name and Version in Rows.

Comment: OK, i just edited and added another way that should give you what you are looking for...

Comment: Thanks a ton this is the thing I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can just retrieve the ChildNodes of the `FIRMWARE_INFORMATION` node and iterate over them:

```
$xml.DocumentElement.RIBCL.GET_EMBEDDED_HEALTH_DATA.FIRMWARE_INFORMATION.ChildNodes | 
    ForEach-Object { "{0} = {1}" -f $_.FIRMWARE_NAME.Value, $_.FIRMWARE_VERSION.Value}
```

**Output:**

```
iLO = 2.40 Dec 02 2015
System ROM = I31 06/01/2015
Redundant System ROM = I31 04/01/2015
Intelligent Provisioning = 1.62.31
Intelligent Platform Abstraction Data = 1.55
System ROM Bootblock = 03/05/2013
Power Management Controller Firmware = 3.3
Power Management Controller Firmware Bootloader = 2.7
System Programmable Logic Device = Version 0x13
Server Platform Services (SPS) Firmware = 2.1.7.E7.4
Smart Array P220i Controller = 6.68
HP FlexFabric 10Gb 2-port 554FLB Adapter = 10.5.155.0
```

**Note:** This will create an array of strings. If you want to get a hashtable because you want to retrieve the values of a key, you have to adopt the foreach object content...

Comment: Thanks for the help, I am trying various combinations provided by both of you, thanks for the quick reply.